# cart does not save the right amount opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart, cart

I've moved the place input quantity in opencart 2.3 and now it does not make the right quantities count in the cart

[product page quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J9jN.png)

[cart quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EndiZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a minute to review guidelines such as [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure your question gets helpful responses.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more details about your edits. 1. what page have you edited, 2. paste the code of your edit. 3. tell us the steps you make to reproduce the error.